# CakePHP 3.x migrations migrate - how to control order

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, database-migration

I've been told that I should create a separate migration file for each table my migration needs, and that I should create these migration files in the correct order so that when I run "bin/cake migrations migrate" I don't get foreign key violations (it was assumed that all migration files would be executed in order of timestamp).

However, after creating 3 test migration files in the correct order, it clearly ignores timestamp and I get foreign key violations.

What is the correct workflow here?

Filenames are:
20160810025756_CreateUserGroups.php
20160810025835_CreateUsers.php

When I run the migration, it runs CreateUsers before CreateUserGroups.

Comment: Could you post your current migration filenames to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

I needed to clear my phinxlog table in the database, from previous attempts I had made while testing all of this out.